# Crime Statistics Analysis: how to properly compare apples to apples?

Tags: inference, predictor, endogeneity

first this is non-partisan. Now, I have heard a lot of people in the news using certain simple statistics such as the number of uses of lethal forces by cops particularly where the victim is a minority to draw the conclusion that there is excessive force and racial bias. I have also heard on Planet Money a comparison to the use of lethal force by law enforcement in the US vs in Britain (https://www.npr.org/transcripts/871298161). Is this really a sufficient analysis from which to draw conclusions? If not what is? Don't we need to ensure we are evaluating the data:

- per capita when comparing separate regions
- removing incidents where lethal force was necessary (e.g. a shootout) from the dataset
- identifying the probability of minority vs. non-minority interaction for an officer given a location's crime statistics and racial statistics

[Again, this is non-partisan, but I would like to see a much more rigorous analysis. I understand that incidents like Floyd's and Eric Garner are abhorrent and should not go unpunished- plus the subsequent defense of these people by the union or fellow officers is at least an indication of a bad system. Furthermore, there seems to be lack of available data sometimes.]

Any links to the type of data analysis I am searching for would be great. Thank you.

Comment: this is an interesting question, but I suggest two improvements: a) remove reference to Floyd because it's USA specific case and it also draws distracting attention from Web searchers who are not interested in stats, b) bring up a specific example of research or article where you have doubts about statistical part of reasoning. Also, your references about "bypartisian" are very USA specific, many countries have effective more than two partis, some countries have one or none, some countries are mono racial, some countries have many parties that are really just one etc. Let's focus on stats

Comment: The answer to your question is in assumptions. For instance, one assumption is that probability that police force usage is justified cannot differ by the race of the subjects. Are you comfortable with this assumption?

Comment: I have declined the flags on the comments by @Aksakal because it is difficult to read them as anything other than constructive.

Comment: here's one reason why assumptions matter. suppose, someone think that minorities are more likely to resist. then *under this assumption* it only makes sense that the force is used against minorities more often: it's because they resist more often. on the other hand, if you go with the alternative - minorities are as likely to resist as majority - then more frequent use of force becomes puzzling. this is why it is important to explicitly state the key assumptions. it is especially important in any discussion involving skin color or gender because people tend to implicitly make assumptions

Comment: @TryingToLearn, if you're trying to learn for real then here's the first thing to learn: there are always assumptions in any analysis. For instance, independence, distributional, random sampling etc. I'm not sure why are you being triggered by a term *assumption*, does it have some colloquial meaning in your language?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be broader than statistics. Maybe it could be stripped of all perceived political context somehow, but in its current formulation it's inappropriate for this forum. The fact that OP feels the need to stress specifically that it's not political is an indication itself of the problem.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your initial question. I am unsure of whether that is a good "assumption" though as opposed to a hypothesis which could be supported or rejected by studies. I was suggesting we only look at cases where lethal force was unjustified so that we don't have to make an assumption like the one you are proposing about minority resistance. It seems such a hypothesis would be irrelevant looking strictly as unjustified lethal force cases.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, in addition to the other comment above, this seems to be asking for analyses already performed, and perhaps a critique of those, rather than how to analyse the data they have. I'm generally not opposed to political-based questions, but this is a real hot-button topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objections you mention are certainly noteworthy considerations. A lot of the issues with statistics on issues like this stem from an endogeneity problem: the error term of the model is correlated with the independent variable, such as race. Specifically, I think it is easy in this case to fall prey to the missing variable bias. That happens when there are unobserved variables (population size, interactions with the police, criminal behavior, mental illness, income, geography) that are related to the response, but not included in the model. These variables may correlate with race in which case their effects are erroneously assigned to race.

If you were to examine police shootings in the United States, and compare cases of white victims and native Hawaiian/pacific islander victims without accounting for anything else, you would attribute the effect of a much higher population to race.  You might conclude that police shoot white people at 300 times the rate at which they shoot native Hawaiin people, but you could not conclude that the effect was due to the difference of race. That example is an oversimplification, and any honest statistic should account for the most obvious covariates such as population size.

However, the process of determining exactly what to control for is complicated and surprisingly subjective. If you look at this paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/116/32/15877 you'll get a picture of a scientific approach to estimating the degree of racial bias in police shootings in the United States. And, if you look at the letters/corrections at the top, you'll also get an idea of some of the controversy involved, and at least one example of how small changes in the analysis can yield conflicting results.

In any case, you can be sure that a single statistic cannot truthfully tell a story as complicated as racial bias in police brutality. And yet, you can be just as sure that they will be used to tell stories, many of which were calculated before the statistic.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Roland Fryer's work in the respected *Journal of Political Economy*: https://scholar.harvard.edu/fryer/publications/empirical-analysis-racial-differences-police-use-force. He finds that

> On nonlethal uses of force, blacks and Hispanics are more than 50 percent more likely to experience some form of force in interactions with police. Adding controls that account for important context and civilian behavior reduces, but cannot fully explain, these disparities. On the most extreme use of force—officer-involved shootings—we find no racial differences either in the raw data or when contextual factors are taken into account.

However, Fryer also notes several limitations to his analysis, including that

> all but one dataset was provided by a select group of police departments. It is possible that these departments only supplied the data because they are either enlightened or were not concerned about what the analysis would reveal...There may be important selection in who was willing to share their data.

Clearly, more research on this topic is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the post and link. This is helpful.